# Find $(m+n)th$ term in given Arithmetic Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

If $n$ times the $m^{th}$ term of an arithmetic progression is equal to $m$ times the $n^{th}$ term, find the $(m + n)^{th}$ term.

Comment: Ok, sorry.. now it's okay

Comment: What you said is

$$ma_m=na_m\Longrightarrow n=m$$

unless $\,a_m=0\,$...
 Are you sure this is what you meant?

Comment: So, what do you think what it should be...

Comment: Ok, I think it should be my writing mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an arithmetic progression $a,a+d,a+2d,...$, the $k$th term is $a+(k-1)d$. Hence $n(a+(m-1)d)=m(a+(n-1)d)$ so that $(n-m)(a-d)=0$. If we assume $n\neq m$, then we have $a=d$. This means that the arithmetic progression is $a,2a,3a,...$ so that the $(m+n)$th term is $(m+n)a$.

Comment: How assuming $n\neq m$ makes $n(a-d)=m(a-d)$ to $a=d$